# Installing a software through group policy

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I want to **install a software through group policy** to the users in a particular OU. I have production OU. I have 4 users in that OU I have to ***apply group policy in such a way that a software should be installed to the users***. These are the steps I tried.

1. Downloaded **7 zip msi** file.
2. Created a shared folder ***programs*** and have put the msi file into that folder.
3. Opened Group policy -> Right Click production OU -> create and link group policy -> named the group policy-> right clicked ->edit->sotware policies->software installation->new package-> selected 7 zip from the file uploader pop up -> advanced -> in the properties, deployment tab checked the ASSIGNED radio button -> then checked Install in LOGON -> OK
4. opened cmd -> **gpupdate**.
5. logged in as another user but din find the software installation.

Where did i go wrong? Can anyone help me with this please. I din find the software in the "INSTALL SOFTWARE THROUGH NETWORK " option too.

Comment: run a GP Modeling wizard in GPMC and verify first that the GPO is to be applied properly to that user.  EDITed...since I missed the "users" part and thought you were wanting to apply to workstations.

Comment: Software policies under "Computer Configuration" or "User Configuration"?

Comment: @ Mathias under User configuration

Comment: @TheCleaner Should we reboot the workstation for every GPO update?

Comment: no...you can do gpupdate /force.  I didn't read it right that you were doing this to the user and not computer.  Computer software GPOs apply at startup.  That's why I edited out my comment.  Also, if it is USER based, I'm pretty sure the user logging in needs the rights to install software on that computer.

Comment: So howto provide rights to the users to install the software? make them as administrators?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Ganesh, you will have to provide the user administrator rights. To avoid this situation you need to change from "User Configuration" to "Computer Configuration" and apply to computers instead users.

If you are applying this to Windows XP computer it may work by adding the user to the Power Users group, but that depends on the software installer, if involves a driver installation will fail because of the need of elevated rights.

From my experience with Windows 7 it work if the user is local administrator of the PC, if not you have to deploy through Computer Configuration instead.

Comment: Its not getting applied even to the workstations. I followed the procedure from this link exactly. Please help to clear this ! http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/installing-software-using-gpos-on-windows-server-2008

Comment: Make sure that you link your GPO to the right OU (Computers must be inside! not users). "EXE-to-MSI" didn't work for me in the past, but I guess you downloaded the 7-zip MSI from the official site. You can also try the command "gpresult /h report.htm" and check the report.htm file and see what was applied to the computer and look for errors.